# I want to get the session value from the controller method on jsp. can someone help me out how i can do this

Tags: java, session

I want to get the session value from the controller method to jsp. can someone help me out how i can do this

controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="customerLogin.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String customerLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException{
String customerEmail=request.getParameter("customerEmail");
String password= request.getParameter("customerPassword");
Boolean isLoggedIn=false;
Customer customer= serviceInter.logincustomer(customerEmail, password);
if(customer!=null){
    isLoggedIn=true;
}
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(isLoggedIn));
session.setAttribute("customerInfo", customer);
return null;
}
```

Let I  need to get that value here

Hello< customername>

Comment: `session.getAttribute("attributeName");`????

Comment: customer name from session obj  customerInfo eg
customerInfo.firstname

Comment: its not working may be becz session.getAttribute("attributeName");  is used to get the value of single string value of session like if i set the name of customer in session but here i  set obj

Answer (score 0):

You could get it by using following statement:

```
Customer customer = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customerInfo");
//System.out.println(customer.getFirstName());
```

Answer (score -1):

How are you retrieving in your JSP?
What is the error you are getting?

```
${customerInfo.name} 
OR 
Customer customer = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customerInfo");
```

2nd option: You can also make the Controller to be session scoped.

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class SessionScopedController
```